# Tag request [basiljs] for basil.js, a Processing inspired JavaScript library for Adobe InDesign

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

We are a group of developers and designers at the Basel Academy of Art and Design in Switzerland.

We recently launched a new library for Adobe InDesign scripting, that brings some of the convenience that visual coders know from Processing. And we would like to introduce a tag for this called "basiljs" on stackoverflow as we would like to use this service as our main support forum. But none of us has enough reputation... :/

http://basiljs.ch/

There has been a report about us on CAN:

http://www.creativeapplications.net/scripts/basil-js-computational-and-generative-design-using-adobe-indesign/

Hope somebody can help. Don't want to wait until somebody would add the tag to an existing question, as we are about to publish our support strategy.

Thanks,
Ludwig

Comment: Just a point, you call it `basil.js` and then ask for the `basiljs` tag... _IF_ there is ever a question that _NEEDS_ this tag then please don't create one that isn't the name of the library...

Answer (score 3):

> as we would like to use this service as our main support forum

**Stack Overflow is *not* a forum!** It is a focused Q&A site meant for getting help with programming problems.

That out of the way, you can't just *request* a tag creation. There has to be a question that needs the tag. I see you have mentioned this in your question, so I suppose you could ask a question about it and then add the tag to it.

**However**, you can't just `use this service as [y]our main support forum` and expect everyone to agree. This is not your website, so if too many bad questions come in with that tag it may be blacklisted.

Comment: Hi Doorknob, sorry for the confusion with the wording. We are well aware what SO is, so please do not worry about this - especially not before you have seen the quality of our questions... ;)

Comment: Ok, so here we have a basil.js related question... I will answer it in 8h as I am not allowed to do it immediately.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339331/how-can-i-dynamically-attach-a-scripting-label-to-a-newly-created-item-in-basil

It would be great if you could add the tag "basil.js" for this. Thanks

Comment: @LudwigZeller ok